# How to link Multiple Auth Providers to an Firebase Account on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I referenced the [documentation in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) page. My problem is in this paragraph:

> The call to linkWithCredential will fail if the credentials are already linked to another user account. In this situation, you must handle merging the accounts and associated data as appropriate for your app:
>
> `FirebaseUser prevUser = currentUser; currentUser = auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await().getUser(); // Merge
>       prevUser and currentUser accounts and data // ...`

I can't figure out how to add this code into my project. When and where do I put this code

```
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await().getUser();
```

into my java file? Android Studio announced me that it can't resolve `await()` method.

What should I do to resolve that problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this part of code when the linkWithCredentials call fails.

Here is a small example :

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credentials).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
           FirebaseUser prevUser = currentUser; 
           try {
             currentUser = Tasks.await(auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).getUser();
           } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackStrace();
           }
           // Merge prevUser and currentUser accounts and data 
           // ...
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

NB: `Task.await()` doesn't exist anymore you should use Tasks.await(...) static method instead.

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: i'm still not. are u?

Comment: @Adrin Lamit from where we will get credentials"linkWithCredential(credentials)" ??

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that:

- `One account per email address` setting is enabled on firebase authentication
- User are logging in with anonymous authentication

The `linkWithCredential` usually fails with `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException`, it could happen either because this credential is used to login before (you can check by searching this email on firebase console) or this email account is used to login before but with different providers ( such as a user logged in with abc@gmail.com by using google sign in before, now he/she uses abc@gmail.com but with Facebook login ) To handle it, you need 2 steps:

**Step 1: link with anonymous account**

```
private void linkWithAnonymousAccount(final AuthCredential credential) {
    mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        getFirebaseToken();
                    } else {
                        Exception exception = task.getException();
                        if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                            signInWithFirebase(credential);
                        } else {
                            Utils.showDialogMessage(mContext, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**Step 2: sign with firebase**

```
private void signInWithFirebase(AuthCredential credential) {        
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        getFirebaseToken();
                    } else {
                        Utils.showDialogMessage(mContext, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Google says the step 2 is merging because after signed in, you need to get information of the previous user and put into the new user.

I hope it helpful.

Comment: What does getFirebaseToken() method?

Comment: If you have your own backend, after authenticating with firebase, you should get firebase token to send to your server for verification. The details could be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: No, I don't have an own backend. How can I go ahead with firebase?

Comment: If you don't have your own backend, you can go forward without getting firebase token id, you can go to main screen activity for example. After login successfully, you can access user info or database that created on firebase console.